# Wso2 api publisher and devportal throwing error in version 4.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have installed Wso2 API manager 4.2.0 on one of my development server.
Post installation, I am able to access the carbon management console successfully.
But when I am trying to access the API publisher and Devportal URLs, It doesnot work

Below is the error encountered in the logs.

```
TID: [-1234] [authenticationendpoint] [2023-11-17 04:47:09,417] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/authenticationendpoint].[default]} - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/authenticationendpoint] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [plugins/basicauth-extensions.jsp] at line [32]

29:         request.setAttribute("errorMsg", AuthenticationEndpointUtil
30:                 .i18n(resourceBundle, "something.went.wrong.contact.admin"));
31:         IdentityManagementEndpointUtil.addErrorInformation(request, e);
32:         request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp").forward(request, response);
33:         return;
34:     }
35:     File typingPatternRecorder = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("plugins/typing-dna.jsp"));


Stacktrace:] with root cause java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313)
        at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:1547)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.filter.AuthenticationEndpointFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationEndpointFilter.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.filter.AuthenticationEndpointFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationEndpointFilter.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:119)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.OrganizationContextRewriteValve.invoke(OrganizationContextRewriteValve.java:116)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.SameSiteCookieValve.invoke(SameSiteCookieValve.java:38)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:165)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:111)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:106)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:152)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:63)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```